# creating a loop for only 10 numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to get a loop created to gather numbers from a temperature sensor

I got a list created to collect and store the data and have the time set up to collect it over intervals but I need to stop collecting after I get 10 numbers

```
# create the list
templist = []

while True:
    try:
        # get the temperature and Humidity from the DHT sensor
        [ temp,hum ] = dht(dht_sensor_port,dht_sensor_type)

        # change temp reading from celsius to fahrenheit
        temp = ((temp/5.0)*9)+32

        # round the temp to 2 decimal places so it will read on the LCD screen
        new_temp = round(temp, 2)

        print("temp =", temp )



        # check if we have nans
        # if so, then raise a type error exception
        if isnan(new_temp) is True or isnan(hum) is True:
            raise TypeError('nan error')

        t = str(new_temp)
        h = str(hum)


        templist.append (new_temp)
        sleep(1)


        print ("the list is as follows" , templist )
```

I am getting proper output but I want it to stop after 10 numbers and this is when it keeps going.  I know I need to create a loop but I keep getting error messages.

Comment: What have you tired and what error messages do you see?

Comment: `for i in range(10)` ?

Comment: lookup the `break` keyword

Comment: What are the *error messages*?

Comment: sorry if I offended anybody but I am new to coding and am trying to learn.

Comment: I don't think anyone is offended here, you got minuses because the question was quite basic. Check basic [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), at least points 1-5. Keep on going and don't get demotivated :)

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(10):
    ...
```

or more idiomatic:

```
for _ in range(10):
    ...
```

creates a loop with 10 iterations.

You could also use `break` keyword in a while loop but that would also require separate variable for iterations count.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are keeping the results in `templist`, you could check the number of items in this list and stop when it reaches 10:

```
templist = []

while len(templist) < 10:
    ...
```

Also, there is no reason to use the `try:` block unless you are going to use an `except` to catch an error. As used in your code, the `try:` doesn't do anything.